# PHP timezone offset incorrect

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, timezone-offset

The following PHP Code:

```
function serverTimeZone_offset($userTimeZone)
{
    $userDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($userTimeZone);
    $userDateTime     = new DateTime("now", $userDateTimeZone);

    $serverTimeZone     = date_default_timezone_get();
    $serverDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($serverTimeZone);
    $serverDateTime     = new DateTime("now", $serverDateTimeZone);

    return $serverDateTimeZone->getOffset($userDateTime);
}

function getDefineTimeZone($timezone)
{
    $userDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
                 return new DateTime("now", $userDateTimeZone);
}

function getServerTimeZone()
{
    $serverTimeZone     = date_default_timezone_get();
    $serverDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($serverTimeZone);

    return new DateTime("now", $serverDateTimeZone);
}

$userDateTime   = getDefineTimeZone('America/Curacao');
$serverDateTime = getServerTimeZone();
$timeOffset     = serverTimeZone_offset('America/Curacao');

var_dump($userDateTime);
var_dump($serverDateTime);
var_dump($timeOffset); // the seconds is incorrect ?!?!

// adding the timezone difference
$userDateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$timeOffset.'S'));

var_dump($userDateTime);
```

**Will output:**

```
object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2014-10-22 17:36:39' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Curacao' (length=15)

object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2014-10-22 23:36:39' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)

int 7200

object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2014-10-22 19:36:39' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Curacao' (length=15)
```

**Which is obviously incorrect. The offset is returning back 7200 seconds (only 2 hours) rather than 21600 seconds (6 hours). Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think uou are misinterpreting the behaviour of `DateTimeZone::getOffset()`. As said in [DateTimeZone php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php):

> This function returns the offset to GMT for the date/time specified in the datetime parameter. The GMT offset is calculated **with the timezone information contained in the DateTimeZone object being used**.

So if server timezone is `Europe/Paris`, then getOffset() will return the 7200 seconds, as Europe/Paris is GMT+01:00, and it is summer time right now, so it is GMT+02:00.

Try using this code instead:

```
function serverTimeZone_offset($userTimeZone)
{
    $userDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($userTimeZone);
    $userDateTime     = new DateTime("now", $userDateTimeZone);

    $serverTimeZone     = date_default_timezone_get();
    $serverDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($serverTimeZone);
    $serverDateTime     = new DateTime("now", $serverDateTimeZone);

    return $serverDateTimeZone->getOffset($userDateTime) - $userDateTimeZone->getOffset($userDateTime);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I indeed completely misinterpreted the behavior of getOffset. Thank you for the simplified clarification.